How to set selected text colour, style in Qtableview string
Below is a small working code to display what I am trying to achieve.
import sys
import os
import sqlite3

from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


# createDB()
# con_1 = sqlite3.connect("temp.db")

#  # create a table
# con_1.execute('''create table t1(
#    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 'First Name' TEXT, 'Last Name' TEXT, 'Full Name' TEXT);''')

# # populate the table
# con_1.execute("insert into t1 ('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Full Name') values('Wade', 'Wilson', 'Wade Wilson');")
# con_1.execute("insert into t1 ('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Full Name') values('Norman', 'Osborn', 'Norman Osborn');")
# con_1.execute("insert into t1 ('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Full Name') values('Stephen', 'Strange', 'Stephen Strange');")
# con_1.commit()
# con_1.close()

class MultilineTextEditor(QStyledItemDelegate):

    def createEditor(self, parent, options, index):
        return QTextEdit(parent)

    def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
        editor.setText(index.data())

    def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
        model.setData(index, editor.toPlainText()) 
    
    def paint(self, painter, option, index):
        value = index.data(Qt.DisplayRole)
        if  option.state & QStyle.State_Selected:
            text1 = index.data()
            doc = QTextDocument(text1)
            cursor = QTextCursor(doc)
            cursor.selectedTableCells()
            # cursor.selectedText()  <-- How to implement this?
            # Trying out to simply select the first line!
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.Start)
            cursor.movePosition(QTextCursor.EndOfLine, QTextCursor.KeepAnchor)
            format = QTextCharFormat()

            format.setFontWeight(QFont.Bold)
            format.setFontPointSize(20)
            weight = QFont.DemiBold
            format.setFontWeight(weight)
            cursor.mergeCharFormat(format)
            print(cursor.selectedText())
            # painter commands??        
            QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
        else:
            QStyledItemDelegate.paint(self, painter, option, index)
            
class TableViewer(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        working_dir = os.getcwd()
        db_path = f"{working_dir}\\temp.db"
        print(db_path)
        self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        self.db.setDatabaseName(db_path)

        self.db.open()

        self.model = QSqlTableModel(self, self.db)   
        self.model.setTable('t1')
        self.model.select()

        self.tableView = QTableView(self)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
        self.tableView.resizeColumnsToContents()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.tableView)
        
        widget = QWidget()
        widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(widget)

        self.tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(3, MultilineTextEditor())
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    tv = TableViewer()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


A SQL Lite Database (temp.db) is created in the commented out sections
This db is read and displayed in a Qtableview
The column containing full names is editable

How would you set the format (bold, Italics, underline), size or colour of selected string? I would eventually bind the selection with say keyboard shorcuts (eg cntr + B for bold) or display a toolbar for user selection.  Found an example here: https://forum.qt.io/topic/138318/how-do-you-bold-and-un-bold-a-selected-text-pyqt-or-pyside. I am unable to implement it, even rudimentarily in a Qtableview cell.
The rich text data should be saved back to be retrieved from the DB. Unfortunately I am unable to find any good explanitions on delegate --> paint.

In what format is or should be stored the rich text data? QTextDocument (which is what QTextEdit also uses) is able to parse HTML and eventually return it, but the resulting contents is often unsuitable (it outputs a lot of HTML even for small strings). In any case, in order to edit the formatting of a QTextDocument you need to work with QTextCursor (as shown in the paint() of your code), while QTextEdit already provides basic helper functions such as setTextColor(). Just check the documentation of the above classes.

@musicamante : Thanks for the suggestions. Yes I did a little experimentations with setData(index, editor.toHtml()), but as you mentioned it outputs too much. I would like to have multiline text and the ability for the user to change format of selected text(s) to bold, Italics or undeline. This formated text should be stored and retrievable in the db. To begin with, making the text bold should suffice for now. The remaining features  and   incorporating it in context menu or toolbox is something I can manage or perhaps ask in a seperate thread.

Qt supports markdown, which has a much cleaner syntax. The problem is that it doesn't provide support for colors, which is what you specifically asked: while you can use inline HTML (for example <span style="color: green;">text</span>) and it is preserved in the QTextDocument with setMarkdown(), the color data is unfortunately lost when exporting back with toMarkdown(). An alternative could be to use specialized libraries to clean up the Qt HTML output. About the actual editing, as said I suggest you to carefully read the QTextEdit docs, along with the QTextDocument/QTextCursor API.

I have found a solution to my question.
Courtesy:

Changing the font color of a QTableView after replacing the default editor with an ItemDelegate QTextEdit in PyQt5

https://forum.qt.io/topic/138318/how-do-you-bold-and-un-bold-a-selected-text-pyqt-or-pyside


import sys
import os
import sqlite3
from functools import partial

from PyQt5.QtSql import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

from wid_comments_editor_v1 import Ui_CommEdit

# createDB()
# con_1 = sqlite3.connect("temp.db")

#  # create a table
# con_1.execute('''create table t1(
#    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 'First Name' TEXT, 'Last Name' TEXT, 'Full Name' TEXT);''')

# # populate the table
# con_1.execute("insert into t1 ('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Full Name') values('Wade', 'Wilson', 'Wade Wilson');")
# con_1.execute("insert into t1 ('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Full Name') values('Norman', 'Osborn', 'Norman Osborn');")
# con_1.execute("insert into t1 ('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Full Name') values('Stephen', 'Strange', 'Stephen Strange');")
# con_1.commit()
# con_1.close()

class CommentEditor(QWidget, Ui_CommEdit):

   """ 
   UI code (Ui_CommEdit) not attached.
   Contains a simple Qtextedit with 5 buttons for bold, italics, underline,
   strikeout and colour
   """    
   closed = pyqtSignal()
   def __init__(self, parent=None):
       QWidget.__init__(self, parent=parent)
       self.setupUi(self)
   
   def closeEvent(self, event):
       self.closed.emit()

   

class MultilineTextEditor(QStyledItemDelegate):

   def createEditor(self, parent, options, index):
       return QTextEdit(parent)

   def setEditorData(self, editor, index):
       txt = index.data()
       editor.setHtml(txt)
       return editor.setHtml(txt)


   def setModelData(self, editor, model, index):
       model.setData(index, editor.toHtml())

   def paint(self, painter, option, index):
       painter.save()
       rich_txt = index.data()
       doc = QTextDocument()
       doc.setTextWidth(option.rect.width())
       doc.setHtml(rich_txt)
       option.text = ""
       option.widget.style().drawControl(
           QStyle.CE_ItemViewItem, option, painter
           )
       painter.translate(option.rect.left(), option.rect.top())
       doc.drawContents(painter)
       painter.restore()



class TableViewer(QMainWindow):

   # close_comment_editor = pyqtSignal()

   def __init__(self):
       super().__init__()
       working_dir = os.getcwd()
       db_path = f"{working_dir}\\temp.db"
       self.db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
       self.db.setDatabaseName(db_path)

       self.db.open()

       self.model = QSqlTableModel(self, self.db)   
       self.model.setTable('t1')
       self.model.select()

       self.tableView = QTableView(self)
       self.tableView.setModel(self.model)
       self.tableView.resizeColumnsToContents()
       layout = QVBoxLayout()
       layout.addWidget(self.tableView)
       
       widget = QWidget()
       widget.setLayout(layout)
       self.setCentralWidget(widget)
       
       # Adjust width of columns and rows
       header_hor = self.tableView.horizontalHeader()
       header_hor.setSectionsMovable(True)
       header_hor.resizeSection(3, 800)
       self.tableView.resizeRowsToContents()

       self.tableView.setItemDelegateForColumn(3, MultilineTextEditor())
               
      
       self.showMaximized()
   
   

   def contextMenuEvent(self, event):
       # Imp! Create new model from existing items on view
       # self.self.tableView != self.tableView.model
       model = self.tableView.model()
       # Indices
       col_indx = self.tableView.currentIndex().column()
       row_indx = self.tableView.currentIndex().row()
       index = model.index(row_indx, col_indx)
       # Get Value
       data = model.data(index)
       # header names
       header_name = []
       for x in range(self.model.columnCount()):
           header_name.append(self.model.headerData(x, Qt.Horizontal))

       selectionModel = self.tableView.selectionModel()
       selectionModel.isSelected(index)

       if header_name[col_indx] == "Full Name" and selectionModel.isSelected(
           index
       ):  
           self.menu = QMenu(self)
           edit = QAction("Edit", self)
           self.menu.addAction(edit)
           self.menu.popup(QCursor.pos())
           edit.triggered.connect(
               partial(
                   self.edit_frontend,
                   data,
                   col_indx,
                   row_indx,
                   header_name,
                   model,
               )
           )


   def edit_frontend(self, data, col_indx, row_indx, header_name, model):
       # Open editor
       self.comm_edit =CommentEditor()
       self.comm_edit.show()
       
       self.comm_edit.te_comment_editor.setHtml(data)

       # Code for bold
       self.comm_edit.pb_bold.clicked.connect(self.bold_text)
       self.comm_edit.pb_bold.setShortcut(Qt.CTRL | Qt.Key_B)
       # Code for italic
       self.comm_edit.pb_italic.clicked.connect(self.italic_text)
       self.comm_edit.pb_italic.setShortcut(Qt.CTRL | Qt.Key_I)
       # Code for underline
       self.comm_edit.pb_underline.clicked.connect(self.underline_text)
       self.comm_edit.pb_underline.setShortcut(Qt.CTRL | Qt.Key_U)
       # Code for strikeout
       self.comm_edit.pb_strikeout.clicked.connect(self.strikeout_text)
       self.comm_edit.pb_strikeout.setShortcut(Qt.CTRL | Qt.Key_S)
       # Code for colour
       self.comm_edit.pb_colour.clicked.connect(self.colour_text)

       # Close event handler
       self.comm_edit.closed.connect(
               partial(
                   self.win_closed,
                   col_indx,
                   row_indx,
                   model,
               )
           )


   def win_closed(self,  col_indx, row_indx,  model  ):
       txt = self.comm_edit.te_comment_editor.toHtml()
       model.setData(model.index(row_indx, col_indx), txt)

   def bold_text(self): 

       fmt = QTextCharFormat()
       if self.comm_edit.pb_bold.isChecked(): 
           weight = QFont.Bold 
       else: 
           weight = QFont.Normal
           
       fmt.setFontWeight(weight)
       self.merge_format_on_word_or_selection(fmt)
   
   def italic_text(self):
       fmt = QTextCharFormat()
       fmt.setFontItalic(self.comm_edit.pb_italic.isChecked())
       self.merge_format_on_word_or_selection(fmt)

   def underline_text(self):
       fmt = QTextCharFormat()
       fmt.setFontUnderline(self.comm_edit.pb_underline.isChecked())
       self.merge_format_on_word_or_selection(fmt)

   def strikeout_text(self):
       fmt = QTextCharFormat()
       fmt.setFontStrikeOut(self.comm_edit.pb_strikeout.isChecked())
       self.merge_format_on_word_or_selection(fmt)

   def colour_text(self):
       color = QColorDialog.getColor()
       if color.isValid():
           fmt = QTextCharFormat()
           fmt.setForeground(color)
           self.merge_format_on_word_or_selection(fmt)

   def merge_format_on_word_or_selection(self, format):
 
       cursor = self.comm_edit.te_comment_editor.textCursor()
       if not cursor.hasSelection(): 
           cursor.select(QTextCursor.WordUnderCursor)
       cursor.mergeCharFormat(format)
       self.comm_edit.te_comment_editor.mergeCurrentCharFormat(format)


   def closeEvent(self, event):
       
       try :
           self.comm_edit.close()
       except AttributeError:
           pass

       event.accept()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   tv = TableViewer()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

   



As mentioned earlier the commented block contains the code to create a SQLLite temp.db.

The entries in Last name column can be modified with opening an UI acessed via a custom context menu.

The edited rich text data is stored as HTML but diplayed as text.


Hope this helps someone!
